# Data passing in Angular2

Tags: angular

I am having login page, i am login using mobile number and an OTP. Initially i am entering the mobile number and click on send OTP and calling a service that will send an OTP to the registered mobile number. Then i am entering the OTP at that time i am hiding the send OTP button and enabling Login button. On clicking login i need to pass both mobile number and otp to the backend services. But i am getting mobile number as undefined on click of second button which is login. How to achieve this in Angular2?

```
          <div>
            <input type="phone" id="mob" name="phone" #mob [(ngModel)]="loginIntData.mobile" class="form-control" onkeyup="validateNumber()" placeholder="Mobile" required="" />
          </div>

        <div>
            <input type="password" id="otp" name="otp" #otp [(ngModel)]="loginIntData.otp" class="form-control" onkeyup="otpValue()" placeholder="Emter OTP" required="" disabled/>
          </div>

        <div>
          <button class="sendbtn" id="otpbtn" class="btn btn-default submit" class="btn" onclick="sendOTP()" (click)="OnSendOTP(loginIntData)" >SEND OTP</button>
          <button id="loginbtn" class="btn btn-default submit" class="btn" routerLink="/landing" (click)="OnLogin(loginIntData)" >LOGIN</button>
        </div>


OnSendOTP(loginIntData : LoginInterface)
{
  this._httpService.OnOtp(loginIntData).subscribe (
       data => this.loginIntData = (data),
        error => alert("error"+error),
        () => console.log("received OTP")


  );
 }

OnLogin(loginIntData : LoginInterface) {
        console.log("Inside login method");
        console.log("mobile" +loginIntData.mobile);
        console.log("otp" +loginIntData.otp);
        this._httpService.Onvalidate(loginIntData).subscribe (
          // (res) => {console.log(res.json())}
             data => this.loginIntData = (data),
              error => alert("error"+error),
              () => console.log("user logged in", loginIntData)
        );
 }
```

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: i have shared the code. Inside OnLogin method mobile number is undefined, as it gets cleared on click of send otp button

Answer (score 0):

you can use a template driven form for it
first import formsModule

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

then in your component or service create a variable

```
mobile: string;
otp: string;
```

then you can bind them to the input

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="mobile">
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="otp">
<input type="submit" (click)="sendfunctionIncomponent()">



 sendfunctionIncomponent(){

    if (mobile&&otp){
    callServiceToSendData().subscribe(res=>{console.log(res)});
    }
}
```